How to prevent escaping with \
I have a filepath that is structured as \\abc\xyz\file.xlsx
I need the first section excluding the file name \\abc\xyz\ with the two \\ in the beginning and the additional one at the end as a string to be stored as a variable ie:
variable1 = "\\abc\xyz\"

Whenever I try and store the string it raises SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
How do I correctly write this so that it doesn't raise an error and keeps all of the \?
I have tried adding an r before the "" or using '' and """ """, all raise the same error.

r"\abc\xyz" would not produce the same error.

@chepner The problem is with a slash at the end, before the closing quote. You couldn't see that until I fixed the question formatting.

Ah, yes, that is a limitation of raw strings. You need to use an explicitly escaped backslash for that. One option would be r'\\abc\xyz''\\' (using juxtaposition to concatenate a raw string literal with an ordinary literal representing the backslash.)
